# Get the old value of editText with TextWatcher

Tags: mvvm, kotlin, textwatcher

I want to get the old value of editText with the function beforeTextWatcher.
The problem is that when I tried to get this old value, the returned value is always null , Someone ca help me please

```
val nomTextWatcher: TextWatcher
        get() = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                userUpdateSignup.setNom(s.toString())

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
               if(!s.toString().isEmpty())                
  userUpdateSignup.setNom(s.toString())

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just using a TextWatcher, you have to store value into the class properties and then check it yourself.

```
private var myFieldValue : String = ""

[...]

val nomTextWatcher: TextWatcher
    get() = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {        
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
           userUpdateSignup.setNom(s.toString())
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            // Here you can check differences or what you want
            if(!s.toString().isEmpty())                
                userUpdateSignup.setNom(s.toString())

            // After text changed, you have to store it 
            myFieldValue = s.toString()
        }
    }
```